# Toggling a bit in a bitmap of chars

Tags: c++, bitmap, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have a bitmap like this:

```
sizeofBitmapInBits = 16; // must be multiple of 8
char* bitmap = new char[sizeofBitmapInBits/8](); // 2 bytes
```

And I want to toggle a single bit of this bitmap, let's say bit n° 11.

Is this correct?

```
int numBit = 11;
int posBitmap = floor(numBit / 8); // this gives me the byte in the bitmap
char ch = bitmap[posBitmap];

int positionInByte = numBit - posBitmap * 8 ; // this gives me the bit in the byte
ch |= 1 << positionInByte; // or ch |= 0 << positionInByte
bitmap[posBitmap] = ch;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks essentially correct, but it's a bit more complicated than it needs to be. The only technical change I'd make would be to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`. Beyond that, you don't need `floor`, and you can use `%` to calculate the bit offset:

```
int index = numBit / 8;
int offset = numBit % 8;
bitmap[offset] |= 1 << offset;
```

As @graygoose124 points out, that will turn a bit on, but won't turn it off. To toggle it, replace `|=` with `^=`. More generally, use

```
bitmap[index] |= 1 << offset;
```

to turn a bit on, and

```
bitmap[index] &= ~(1 << offset);
```

to turn a bit off, and

```
bitmap[index] ^= 1 << offset;
```

to toggle a bit.

Comment: Is seems to me that there is an error in your code, because you calculated `index` but never used it

Comment: @l19 - D'oh! Changed `offset` to `index` in the three places where it's used to index into the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I took a brief overlook and almost everything is(seems) in order with the exception of `|=`. (Though, I feel that it could be done more easily)

Currently, your code will toggle a bit on, but if you try to toggle it off, nothing will happen. (`1 | 1 = 1`, `1 | 0 = 1` )

Instead, you should use `^=`, because `1 ^ 1 = 0` and `0 ^ 1 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it even simpler then @Pete Becker answer, why not use bitset (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/):

```
#include <bitset>
std::bitset<16> bitmap;

int numBit = 11;
bitmap.flip(numBit);
```

Comment: Too easy. Programmers like pain.